# Honda CB shine starting issue

Tags: honda, starting

I have bought  a new Honda bike (model code-CBF-125F, model name-CB shine) ,when I start the bike in the morning ,I need to use choke. After reaching work place ,it keeps standing idle their for 7-8 hours, again I need to use choke. Sometimes choke is required after 3-4 hours. And sometimes when does not start with choke, then I start bike by opening some throttle.There is hot climate here.

Is it normal practice or problem to start this and also plz tell me why this feature has been added in the bike.

Yogesh charaya
From-sonipat, haryana

Comment: In the context of your question, the model year would be more useful than its date of purchase (I cannot tell if your purchase was brand new or second-hand). Also, do you live in a cold climate?

Comment: I am not satisfied by the answer because I get the petrol from Authorizer dealer of reliance

Answer (score 1):

It is normal behaviour to use the choke when starting the engine from cold. That's what a choke is for.

> Choke valves are important for normally aspirated gasoline engines
>   because small droplets of gasoline do not evaporate well within a cold
>   engine. By restricting the flow of air into the throat of the
>   carburetor, the choke valve reduces the pressure inside the throat,
>   which causes a proportionally greater amount of fuel to be pushed from
>   the main jet into the combustion chamber during cold-running
>   operation. Once the engine is warm (from combustion), opening the
>   choke valve restores the carburetor to normal operation, supplying
>   fuel and air in the correct stoichiometric ratio for clean, efficient
>   combustion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_valve

Comment: While this is an accurate description, very few motorcycles actually have a choke anymore. It's an enrichener circuit, that just dumps unmetered fuel into the intake.

Comment: Eric is that simply a choke in reverse? My cb600f has the enrichiner circuit but still called a choke. I guess the term choke is synonymous with both, people don't care if it's less air or more fuel as long as it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to have to use the choke when starting a cold engine. The term cold is relative to an engine's normal operating temperature, not ambient conditions. Yes, ambient conditions have an effect from the stand point of the colder it is, the longer the choke may need to be engaged during warmup.

So, each time the engine cools significantly, you will need to use the choke to start it. The choke may not be needed for long, but just to assist the starting. Obviously, when  the engine is still warm it may not be necessary to use the choke.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using poor fuel.  Try using fuel from a different supplier.

Answer (score 0):

How much choke are you using to start and in what conditions? I wouldn't worry too much. My CB600F Hornet is the same, I need the choke unless I've just ridden it or if it's a warm day cold engine it needs about half choke.